# MySQL efficient and correct linking of GROUP BY results

Tags: mysql

is there some efficient way how to write queries that join various results of GROUP BYs on a common table? How MySQL handles merging results of aggreagate functions ona a subGROUP with full fields from original table?

i am using this and its slow (and i need also other condition than CONDITION=1)

```
SELECT a.CID,a.AS_ALL,b.AS_ACTIVE FROM 
            (SELECT CID,COUNT(DISTINCT RAID) AS AS_ALL FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY CID) a
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT CID,COUNT(DISTINCT RAID) AS AS_ACTIVE FROM MYTABLE WHERE CONDITION=1 GROUP BY CID ) b ON a.CID=b.CID;
```

also is it save to use something like?? will MySQL always correctly merge  COLUMN_A with results of aggregation?

```
SELECT  COLUMN_A COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_A), SUM(COLUMN_A),SUM(COLUMN_B) FROM ATABLE WHERE CONDITION=1 GROUP BY COLUMN_C
```

Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CID,COUNT(DISTINCT RAID) AS AS_ALL,SUM(IF(CONDITION=1, 1, 0)) AS AS_ACTIVE 
FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY CID
```